# remove li class & id for menu items and pages list

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Example of WordPress default CSS class output:

```
<li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-55">

<li class="page_item page-item-37">
```

The menu and pages list item come with various own li `class` and `id`.

How to remove them in `functions.php` file for the menu and for the pages list?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? They allow you to have very specific targeting when you write CSS for them.

Comment: dont use it , and look hideous in the html.
in css you can target and style them anyways without those id's and classes

Comment: Not realiably you can't, at least not without alienating a good portion of the users on the web, the only way you'll get enough specificity is using CSS2/CSS3 selectors, which aren't going to work for every user, see the quirks mode site for compatibility info: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be able to remove them by hooking into a couple of filters and returning empty arrays or strings rather than new classes or ids:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
  return is_array($var) ? array() : '';
}
```

---

If you wanted to keep particular classes you could do something like this:

```
function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
  return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item')) : '';
}
```

Comment: What if you wanted to keep a css class thats only being used for the current page? 

Example:
<a class="current-menu-item" href="#">link</a>

Comment: @Richard M Is there a difference between using add_filter('','', 100, 1) and add_filter('','', 10, 2)? Because when searching for the filter, the codex example uses 10, 2. Thanks.

Comment: this work. thanks but i want active custom css. i mean form admin if i put css class then that will show .. any idea how

Answer (score 4):

this is an addition on top of Richard answer.

in case you want to change the current-menu-item class to something else.

```
        add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
        add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
        function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
            if(is_array($var)){
                $varci= array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item'));
                $cmeni = array('current-menu-item');
                $selava   = array('selectedmenu');
                $selavaend = array();
                $selavaend = str_replace($cmeni, $selava, $varci);
            }
            else{
                $selavaend= '';
            }
        return $selavaend;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix that I've come up with.  It removes all the id's and classes from the wp_nav_menu, but allows you to come up with your own "approved" list of classes and/or id's.  It also changes the lengthy "current-menu-item" to "active".  If you prefer to keep the the default WordPress CSS styles, just delete that section of the code.  For the sake of keeping this post minimal, here are the links to the pastebin with the code:
http://pastebin.com/W16cxDfY - for your functions.php file
http://pastebin.com/CGx4aprf - for your template, wherever the menu goes

Answer (score 2):

simply `add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', '__return_false');` for menu item id

Answer (score 2):

Best way to remove li is: Tested and Verified

```
           <?php
            $menuParameters = array(
              'theme_location'  => 'header-menu-top', 
              'container'       => false,
              'echo'            => false,
              'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
              'depth'           => 0,
            );
            echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove all the list classes and id's, add this to functions.php

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'filter_menu_id');
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'filter_menu_li' );
function filter_menu_li(){
    return array('');   
}
function filter_menu_id(){
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Richard's answer:
We need to clean up the empty classes left behind:

```
//Strip Empty Classes
add_filter ('wp_nav_menu','strip_empty_classes');
function strip_empty_classes($menu) {
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class=(["\'])(?!active).*?\1/','',$menu);
    return $menu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => false, // param important
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '',
    'depth'           => -1,
    'walker'          => ''
);

ob_start();
echo preg_replace( '#<li[^>]+>#', '<li>', wp_nav_menu( $defaults ) );
$mainNav = ob_get_clean();

// In the page :
echo $mainNav;
```