# remove article classes & ids for post list

Tags: wordpress

I already [read an inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222140/remove-li-class-id-for-menu-items-and-pages-list), where a person tried to remove various classes of a wordpress html file using the functions.php, with sucess. Now I also want to clean up some code, that is given to articles like here by default:

```
<article class="post-141 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-news entry">
```

Final code should become:

```
 <article class="post entry">
```

Comment: in your `php` file, is your code like this: `<article <?php post_class( ); ?>...`?

Comment: No the code gets generated using the CMS automatically. There has to be a filter function that could be used, to empty the array

Comment: which php file are you looking at?

Comment: I also want to create a filter inside my functions.php but I do not know which function prints out these css classes & ids

Comment: Which is the theme currently you are working on?

Comment: Genesis framework... but I do not think it has to do with the theme, but wordpress cms files itself

Comment: @leftside: there is a post_class(); function inside my theme.. but how can I clean the code up except for the classes post and entry?